# Decode an array of JSON keys

Tags: json, swift, decode, moya

I have this `JSON` data:

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Paris",
      "country_code": "FR",
      "attractions": [
        "CityHall",
        "Theatre",
        "Port"
      ],
      "population": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Nice",
      "country_code": "FR",
      "attractions": [
        "CityHall"
      ],
      "population": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Berlin",
      "country_code": "DE",
      "attractions": [
        "Theatre",
        "Port"
      ],
      "population": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Munich",
      "country_code": "DE",
      "attractions": [
        "Theatre"
      ],
      "population": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Amsterdam",
      "country_code": "NL",
      "attractions": [
        "Theatre",
        "Port"
      ],
      "population": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Leiden",
      "country_code": "NL",
      "attractions": [
        "CItyHall",
        "Theatre"
      ],
      "population": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm decoding it with Moya `.request(.getCities).map([City].self, atKeyPath: "cities")` using object:

```
struct City {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let countryCode: String
  //let attractions: [Attraction]
  let population: Int
}

extension City: Decodable  {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
    case countryCode = "countryCode"
    //case attractions = "attractions"
    case population = "population"
  }
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    countryCode = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .countryCode)
    //attractions = try container.decode([Attraction].self, forKey: .attractions)
    population = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .population)
  }
}
```

Simple and pretty but the problem is I can't figure out how to fit that `attractions` array into here. I have it as `enum` and tried to get keys by using `codingPath`

```
enum Attraction: String {
    case CityHall
    case Theatre
    case Port
}

extension Attraction: Decodable  {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    // confusion mode initiated :) do I use it the same as in struct here?
    case cityHall = "CityHall"
    case theatre = "Theatre"
    case port = "Port"
  }
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
    let attraction = container.codingPath.first!.stringValue // that would get the first key into string but how to deal with enum?
  }
}
```

Also, if that would decode `attractions` fine, will the `City` object decode the nested object/array ok?

Comment: `atractions` is misspelled in your JSON. Can you do anything about that?

Answer (score 4):

> Simple and pretty

No, simple and pretty is

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let cities : [City]
}

struct City : Decodable {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let countryCode: String
  let atractions: [Attraction] // note the misspelling
  let population: Int
}

enum Attraction: String, Decodable {
    case cityHall = "CityHall", theatre = "Theatre", port = "Port"
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result.cities)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Judging from the line "Decoding it with `.map([CIty].self, atKeyPath: "cities")`", OP seems to be using Moya, in which case decoding would now look like `map([City].self, atKeyPath: "cities", using: decoder)`, and you would not need `Root`.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, yes, but the OP should mention that somewhere. I just wanted to provide a *simple and pretty* solution.

Comment: I understand. My comment is _mostly_ for the OP's sake.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vadian! It looks _simple and pretty_ indeed :) You didn't use `init(from decoder:`. That's why..? Also yeah, I'm using Moya but from your answer, I'm judging I only need to specify String values for enum and it will be decodable. Will try that now

Comment: I don't use `init(from decoder:` because you get a synthsized standard implementation for free.